# "Upgrading" from Ubuntu 14.04 server to Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: 14.04, server, partitioning, 20.04, upgrade

I have to do an upgrade on a server running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with 200 GB of data on it. What I know so far, is that I must do a clean install for the Ubuntu 20.04 server (upgrading is not an option between the two versions).

The question would be, how can I upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 with keeping the data safe?
I thought something like making a new partition from the rest of the free space (4 TB total, 200GB used), and install the new system on it, so the previous data will be untouched and I will be able to mount it anytime on the new system.
Can I make this happen with an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server installer?

Context: The previous administrator left and I have to make this upgrade, where we host web and email servers for ourselves.

I am quiet new to the Linux ecosystem in this field, so I may say some silly things :).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't.  You need to upgrade 14.04 to 16.04 to 18.04 to 20.04.  And each step along the way the risk of things breaking is **extremely** high.  14.04 and 16.04 are both end of life.  The only thing you can safely do is a clean install of 20.04 and then attempt to migrate your data and sites over.  however, if the system is *that* old chances are the applications and websites and email and such will not behave properly on 20.04 and will need a LOT more experience to get this working and functioning.

Comment: Your workplace might do better to hire a linux systems administrator on a consultant basis for this migration project instead.

Comment: Okay, so I guess the best thing to the is try to backup the data to an external hard drive then setup the new environment and upload the content back. 
Well, thank you!

Comment: What sort of data are you migrating? If it's flat files, then the process will be easy. If it's databases or files that require a specific application (such as a NoSQL database), then you're going to be in for a rough ride. As @ThomasWard has already said, perhaps hiring an experienced Linux person would be the way to go for this project ...

Comment: The data mostly consists of websites with PHP backend and MySQL databases, there are no Node or NoSQL applications. Just some wordpress and custom websites. There are a lot of media files (especially videos) that consumes the most space.

Comment: @krisznitro_ I guess you may expect some incompatibilities between PHP versions used in both systems, ie. some code that worked with the older PHP might not work with the newer and will require changes.
You will also have to dump the old MySQL databases to text (SQL) format and reload them to the new MySQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your production web and email server, then it's likely that something will break when attempting this upgrade. My advice would be to do a fresh install on a new machine, copy your data across, get it all working, then turn off the old server *after* verifying that the new one works as a replacement. If you can't get a new machine, then plug in an extra hard drive, do the install to the new hard drive (if you are unsure, physically disconnect the cable from the old drive while running the installer). After install, boot, mount the old drive read-only, copy the data, and verify the new install. Once you are happy that everything works as it should, don't delete/repartition/alter the existing drive, just swap it out for the new one. With this approach, if something goes wrong, you can always revert back to the old machine (or drive) quickly and easily.

Comment: If you can't get a new machine, you can try to use some cloud instance (for example on AWS) with Ubuntu Server 20.04 installed, set up everything on that temporary machine (you don't need to copy the media files, there should be no problems with them; website code and databases are what's most important), and then copy to the proper one.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I chose Azure to test the new setup, and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

> The data mostly consists of websites with PHP backend and MySQL databases ...

With this in mind, you will need to do quite a bit of testing. Ubuntu 14.04 shipped with PHP 5.3.2 by default (and later 5.6 if the effort was made), which is quite a bit different from the PHP 7.2+ that you'll find in Ubuntu 20.04. The same can be said about MySQL, which was 5.5. The newer MySQL 8.x is *vastly* different and may require a bit of attention given the number of data types that have been deprecated/dropped over the years.

The most effective way to handle this would be to:

1. Create a virtual machine in VirtualBox (or another VM that you're familiar with)
2. Restore the MySQL databases from your most recent backup
3. Fix what fails
4. Restore the websites from your most recent backup
5. Fix what fails
6. Build your production environment and migrate the working data

If this is your first foray into the world of Linux, MySQL, and PHP, it can seem overwhelming. However, taking things bit by bit, you can overcome these challenges and earn a "Miracle Worker" badge at the day job ‍